# Curses window in Python without clearing the terminal

Tags: python, curses

Is there a way to initialize curses in Python without clearing the existing text in the terminal? What I have in mind is, that when I will execute my application, it will either "push" the existing text up and executes at the bottom of the screen, or will draw itself over the existing text. I think curses' `newterm` function can do that, but it isn't implemented in Python. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

For simple applications, e.g. when you just want to use colour, you can try the `curses.setupterm` function.  The following example uses curses to print red and green text at the bottom of the screen:

```
import curses

curses.setupterm()

black_bg = curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setab"), 0)
red = curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setaf"), 1)
green = curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setaf"), 2)
white = curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setaf"), 7)

print black_bg+white+"This is "+red+"red"+white
print "and this is "+green+"green"+white+"."
```